# How can the light conditions be modified in order to avoid the colours to fade in relation with distance?

Tags: light

I am having some troubles with the light conditions in Blender. I am rendering images with a Renault Twizy which has an Aruco Marker printed on it. On distances between the range 1-5m, the Aruco Marker has a strong black. Once I increase the distance, the colour of the Aruco Markers fades away till a grey. I tried to adjust the light conditions with all types of lights in different combinations and positions but the results are more or less similar - same grey colour on further distances.

What can I do in order to maintain the strong black for further distances?

Thanks in advance for your help. I appreciate.

[image][image]

Comment: How are you rendering this? What Render Engine, Cycles, Internal, Game Engine? How is your lighting setup? How is your scene, is there any volumetrics involved? Please edit your question and provide more details and screenshots of your scene.

Comment: There's a node called "Light Falloff" to change how the light intensity decreases over space, but this is not what you need. Is hard to see what kind of illumination you are using or how you set up the shader for the aruco marker, but I notice different reflections between both images. ... So your problem most likely is the angles of the ligh(s) in relation to the car, if you upload the blend file maybe I can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by checking the **Environment Lightning** option at "World" tab. Afterwards, I eliminated all the points, lamps, sun etc and I have a clear view of the marker at further distance.

[image]

Thanks for your willingness to help.